# How to format my coordinates value for seconds as double?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert a list of coordinates from decimal degrees to DMS...it works quite good, but the seconds value still an integer, I need it as a double value for a higher precision. My code so far

```
Function Convert_Degree(Decimal_Deg) As Variant
    With Application
        'Set degree to Integer of Argument Passed
        Degrees = Int(Decimal_Deg)
        'Set minutes to 60 times the number to the right
        'of the decimal for the variable Decimal_Deg
        Minutes = (Decimal_Deg - Degrees) * 60
        'Set seconds to 60 times the number to the right of the
        'decimal for the variable Minute
        Seconds = Format(((Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60), "0")
        'Returns the Result of degree conversion
       '(for example, 10.46 = 10~ 27  ' 36")
        Convert_Degree = " " & Degrees & " deg " & Int(Minutes) & "' " _
            & Seconds + Chr(34)
    End With
End Function
```

The format is exactly the way I need, but the seconds value needs to be a double value...I can't get this to work when I set `Dim Seconds As Double`for example. Any idea?

Comment: Remove the `Format` from `Seconds = Format(((Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60), "0")` so you get `Seconds = (Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60` and declare it as `Double` in the beginning `Dim Seconds As Double`. • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* and declare **all** your variables properly.

Comment: You can change `"0"` in Format function of seconds to `"0.00000"` to get results to 5 decimal places. I tried and it worked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change `"0"` in Format function of seconds to `"0.00000"` to get results to 5 decimal places. As there is no Declaration in Function of the Variables, Excel will do the Rest.

```
Seconds = Format(((Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60), "0.00000")
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables properly and format in the very end. Note that every variable that is not declared is automatically of type `Variant` but `Variant` is the worst type you can choose. If you can, always try to specify a type that suits your needs better.

Also the `With Application` block is completely useless and can be removed.

```
Option Explicit

Function Convert_Degree(Decimal_Deg As Double) As String
    Dim Degrees As Long
    Degrees = Int(Decimal_Deg)

    Dim Minutes As Double
    Minutes = (Decimal_Deg - Degrees) * 60

    Dim Seconds As Double
    Seconds = (Minutes - Int(Minutes)) * 60

    Convert_Degree = " " & Degrees & " deg " & Int(Minutes) & "' " & Seconds & Chr(34)
    'or use the one below to format it 
    'Convert_Degree = " " & Degrees & " deg " & Int(Minutes) & "' " & Format$(Seconds, "0.00000") & Chr(34)
End Function
```